# IOS - Background color for UITableController section footer

Tags: ios, objective-c

Can anyone enlighten me on how to make the uitableview footer have a clear background?

I have added a 15 height footer which is added via the following -

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if (section==0){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        return  15;
    }
}
```

that works fine - but the footer is a grey strip - the tableview has a background image - so i'd like the footer to be clear - is this possible?  if so how do i style it?

Comment: you've to implement that in `- (UIView*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {` method. `return` any view with `clearcolor`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### **We have a better solution for this from iOS6 onwards:**

There is a delegate method `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayFooterView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);`

You can use this method like this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayFooterView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section {

    //Set the background color of the View
    view.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    //Set the TextLabel Color
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *header = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;
    [header.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Implement the `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section` delegate and return a `UIView` in it with clear background.
You could also try setting the `[self.table setTableFooterView:nil]`
That should solve the issue.